# Trying to implement simple BFS in python...Not able to print the value if search is successful

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

Below code is a simple implementation of BFS in Python. I able to print the values level by level from a tree. However when I want to search a element and print it . I am not able to do it. Whts is the error?

```
    def search_bfs(self,root,key):
        q=QueueClass()
        q.enqueue(root)
        while q.size() > 0:
            curr_node = q.dequeue()
            #print curr_node
            #print key
            if curr_node == key:
                print curr_node
                break
            if curr_node.left is not None:
                q.enqueue(curr_node.left)
            if curr_node.right is not None:
                q.enqueue(curr_node.right)
from QueueClass import QueueClass
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.left=None
        self.right=None

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

class searchtree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def create(self,val):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root=Node(val)
        else:
            current=self.root
            while 1:
                if val < current.data:
                    if current.left:
                        current=current.left
                    else:
                        current.left=Node(val)
                        break
                if val > current.data:
                    if current.right:
                        current=current.right
                    else:
                        current.right=Node(val)
                        break
                else:
                    break
tree=searchtree()
lst=[3,1,2,6,4,5,8,12]
for i in lst:
    tree.create(i)
tree.search_bfs(tree.root, 3)
```

Comment: Can *you* tell *us* what is the error? Is it just that nothing is printed? Is the `curr_node == key` line definitely being reached? How do you know?

Comment: Yeah nothing is printed. the statment inside curr_node == key is not being reached, even when I pass a key element matching to root. However printing curr_node prints all the members.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the elements? What kind of objects are they?

Comment: As @VHarisop implies, the problem is likely with your values - can you provide the full code for what you're passing into search_bfs()?

Comment: Got it. I just checked its type and its of type of 'object'. I need to used curr_node.data in the if statement. Let me know if I have understood it.

Comment: Ref the custom `QueueClass`, you may not be aware of the built-in https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html

Comment: @TomDalton, that's only worth it if you need thread safety (you're paying for it!-).  `list` for LIFO, `collections.deque` for FIFO, are the preferred choices in Python.

Answer (score 2):

You really make it hard to reproduce your problem!  So here's what I did:

```
class QueueClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = []
    def size(self): return len(self.l)
    def enqueue(self, it): self.l.append(it)
    def dequeue(self): return self.l.pop()

class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, left=None, right=None):
        self.name = name
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}:{}/{}'.format(self.name, self.left, self.right)

root = Node('root')
```

adding all the code you omitted (more than you supplied!-).

And now, adding your code exactly as reported, the call:

```
search_bfs(None, root, root)
```

emits

```
root:None/None
```

exactly as desired and contrary to your report.

It follows that your bug is in some of code you **didn't** show us, not in the coded you **did** show.

You either have a buggy queue-class, or are building a different tree than you thought, or searching for a node that is not actually in the tree.

Hard to debug code you're now showing, you know.

Added: so now I've integrated the extra code per your edit and at the end I have:

```
st = searchtree()
st.create('imtheroot')
st.search_bfs(st.root, st.root)
```

and of course it prints `imtheroot` as expected.

Is your bug perhaps **STILL** hiding in parts you're not yet showing, e.g instead of looking for a node you may be looking for something else?

E.g, if the final call was erroneously `st.search_bfs(st.root, 'imtheroot')` then obviously the search would fail -- you're checking equality of the `key` parameter **with a node**, so `key` clearly must be a node. not a string or other things (unless the `Node` class defines a very, very peculiar `__eq__` method, which the one you've shown fortunately doesn't:-).

Comment: Thanks Alex. I was comparing a key to a node. I hv fixed it now.

Comment: @user1743585, so pls accept an answer, either my very long one or Tom's concise one, so this issue can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that when you do `if curr_node == key`, `curr_node` is a Node object, which has an integer `.data` attribute, but `key` is the integer value.

So I think you just need to use `if curr_node.data == key`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Tom. I was doing the same mistake. Comparing a Node type to a integer.